# Bringing coffee capsules to US

Tags: usa, food-and-drink

I will shortly flight from EU->US and I was wondering whether it is OK to bring unused sealed coffee capsules (e.g. Nespresso capsules) or I will have troubles at Customs? Do I need to declare them?

Comment: Why carry them? Nespresso products are freely available in the US. Buy when you arrive.

Comment: They are bought already... home surplus :)! (btw, the price is higher in the US, although that is not the reason)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[According to CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3619/%7E/travelers-bringing-food-into-the-u.s.-for-personal-use):

> You must declare all food products.  Failure to declare food products can result in up to $10,000 in fines and penalties.
>
> The following are generally admissible:
>
> (...)
>
> -Coffee - roasted or unroasted if there is no pulp attached.

So, there should be no problem with coffee capsules as long as they are for your personal use, but you do have to declare them.